# Checking whether an Angular2 form is valid or not from within the component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to check whether a form is valid or not to prevent further execution if it is not.

Here is my form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="updateFirstName(firstNameForm)" #firstNameForm="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="getCssClasses(formCtrl, formCtrl.firstName)">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text"
                   ngControl="firstName"
                   #firstName="ngForm"
                   required
                   minlength="2"
                   maxlength="35"
                   pattern_="FIRST_NAME_PATTERN"
                   [ngModel]="currentUserAccount?.firstName"
                   (ngModelChange)="currentUserAccount ? currentUserAccount.firstName = $event : null"
                   placeholder="{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.NEW_FIRST_NAME'| translate }}"
                   class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div [hidden]="firstName.valid">
            <div *ngIf="firstName?.errors?.minlength" class="control-label">{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.MIN_LENGTH'| translate}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="buttonDisabled">{{'FIRST_NAME_FORM.SUBMIT'| translate}}</button>
        <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/useraccount']" class="btn btn-link pull-right text-right">{{'FORM_CANCEL' | translate}}</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, when I submit an invalid form, I notice in the console that the valid attribute of `NgForm` is `true`...

```
 updateFirstName(firstNameForm) {
   console.log(firstNameForm);//the valid attribute of firstNameForm is true...
 }
```

Can anyone please let me know why this is the case?

Comment: Is it intentional that `pattern` in `pattern_="FIRST_NAME_PATTERN"` has an additional `_`? What is `formCtrl`? `ng-class` should be `[ngClass]`

Comment: Yes I am migrating an ng1 app and I assume those `pattern_` and `ng-class` are just ignored.

Comment: Yes, they are just ignored.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are doing template driven forms. Please refer to this simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IElMhx2Kcos7VLrI2QfC?p=preview)

```
<h1>Employee Form</h1>
<form #personForm="ngForm" (submit)="personFormSubmit(personForm)" novalidate>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input id="nameInput" type="text" name="name"
                   ngControl="name"
                   required
                   minlength="2"
                   maxlength="35"
                   [(ngModel)]="person.name" />
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div style="color: red">{{validationMessage}}</div>
</form>
```

and then the controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, ControlGroup, Control, Validators, FormBuilder, Validator, } from '@angular/common';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

export class Person {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    person: Person;
    validationMessage: string;

    constructor() {
        this.person = new Person();
        this.validationMessage = "";
    }

    personFormSubmit(personForm: ControlGroup) {
        if (personForm.valid) {
          this.validationMessage = "Form Is Valid";
        }
        else
        {
          this.validationMessage = "Form Is Not Valid";
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to move to more complex dynamic validation then it would be better to convert to Model driven Forms. As with this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dqPDAKmvAcKS05aZvVsL?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

That's the intended behavior

I found in the change log for 2.0.0-alpha.46 (2015-11-11)

> Previously, the controlsErrors getter of ControlGroup and ControlArray returned the errors of their direct children. This was confusing because the result did not include the errors of nested children (ControlGroup -> ControlGroup -> Control). Making controlsErrors to include such errors would require inventing some custom serialization format, which applications would have to understand. Since controlsErrors was just a convenience method, and it was causing confusing, we are removing it. If you want to get the errors of the whole form serialized into a single object, you can manually traverse the form and accumulate the errors. This way you have more control over how the errors are serialized.

Then the docs for `ControlGroup` and `ControlArray` should be updated

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6504#issuecomment-171950667

You can check if `firstNameForm.valid` is `false` and then iterate the control groups and controls for errors.

The `NgForm` class has the `errors` property because it inherits from `AbstractControlDirective` but the errors from nested controls are not collected there.