# Checking whether an Angular4 form is valid or not from within the component

Tags: angular

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240284/3534027) deals with Angular2, but since there have been a number of changes to Angular in Angular4 with forms, this solution does not work.  Anyone have any idea on how to do this (without having to deal with FormGroups, etc).  Basically, how can I get that answer work with Angular4?

Comment: I am also aware that ngNavtiveValidate exists, but I want to validate the form since this component is in a slider (swiperjs).  Also, using ngNativeValidate causes some weird navigation issues.  So if I could just get the errors and present a message to the user, that would be much easier.  I can create some methods to handle this and use a click event but I am a lazy developer :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the link you provided uses beta version of angular. It imports the `FormBuilder, Validator and etc` from `@angular/common`.
You must import the FormsModule in your app.module from `@angular/forms` like this

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
   //... more code
```

Second, there are two ways that you can use the angular forms, template-driven and model-driven ( reactive forms ). Since you didn't provide any sample code that you are working on, here's a sample in reactive form

```
form: FormGroup;

onSubmit(){
    //checks if form is valid
       if( this.form.valid){
          //more code here
        }
}
```

You really need to use the FormGroup in your code, but you can use the FormBuilder in order not to use FormControls.

```
 form: FormGroup;

  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.email]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(6)]],
      }
    );


  }
```